# Link-local and global IPs on IPv6 interfaces

Tags: ipv6

I'm currently trying to understand how IPv6 adresses work. There are link-local and site-local adresses used for small and organisational networks respectively. But if one of those clients also has internet access, it would need two IPs, correct? One link/site-local and one global adress. How is that managed by the interface and the routers? One interface would need two IPs, since there is no NAT in IPv6.

Comment: This rather belongs to http://serverfault.com/; maybe moderators will transfer the question, or you can re-ask it there.

Comment: There are certainly programming-related aspects to the question.  Some applications may need to fold the list of interface addresses into some algorithm, and it helps to know what sort of addresses you're working with when you get them back from `getifaddrs()`.

Comment: link-local are for not for small networks, they are for unconfigured networks.  Important shortfall being unable to use link-local addresses in DNS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In general, interfaces have one link-local scope unicast address and zero or more global scope unicast addresses.  (They may be also members of some finite number of multicast groups.)  Addresses may be assigned manually or by DHCPv6 as in IPv4, but they may also sometimes (not always) be automatically generated when the router advertisements permit it.  Some host implementations will automatically generate a persistent global address for each prefix the router advertises and an ancillary privacy address to go along with it, c.f. [RFC 4191](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4191).  Where DHCPv6 is used to assign addresses, hosts might request one or more temporary addresses to use instead of privacy addresses.

Don't use site-local addresses.  They're deprecated by [RFC 3879](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3879), mainly because the `sin6_scope_id` field isn't well-defined for site-local addresses.  Applications that see them in the list returned from `getifaddrs()` should probably discard them with a diagnostic message to the standard error stream.  Applications should expect that network administrators will use Unique Local Addresses (ULA) instead of site-local addresses, c.f. [RFC 4941](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941).

The reachability of ULA addresses is not generally decidable by application software.  The only thing you know for certain about them is that they aren't reachable by any path that passes through the global public default-free zone.  They may be reachable from anywhere on the Internet where the routes to the ULA prefix are exchanged in bilateral agreements between autonomous systems.  On the other hand, they will often be advertised by IPv6 home gateways for subscriber local use only, and won't be reachable anywhere outside the home, c.f. [I-D.ietf-v6ops-ipv6-cpe-router](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-v6ops-ipv6-cpe-router).

Answer (score 9):

Every interface has a link-local address and optionally one or more public or site-local addresses. Looks like this:

```
$ ip -o -6 addr show dev eth0
eth0    inet6 2001:abcd:ef::1/64 scope global (..)
eth0    inet6 fe80::1234:5678:2/64 scope link (...)
```

When sending something, everything sent to a link-local address (i.e. `fe80::/64`) is sent from the link-local address, everything else from the global one.

(The choice is not always possible: e.g. if answering to a ping, the source IP of the answer will be the destination IP of the request, no matter which address.)

Comment: Down-voted because site-local addresses are deprecated by [RFC 3879](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3879) and should not be used.  Most IPv6 host implementations don't handle them properly anyway.

Comment: I disagree that this should be downvoted, @phihag is refering to link-local addresses not site-local. In other words, if I'm sending to another `fe80::/64`, that is valid.

Comment: Does this mean that if I only see a `scope link` address, it implies that my ISP (or whatever the greater network) doesn't offer IPv6 connectivity?

Comment: @Iizuki Yes, assuming there is no router between your device and the ISP, then only seeing `scope link` addresses usually means your ISP doesn't offer IPv6 connectivity.
Of course, in practice, all kinds of misconfigurations and special circumstances can exist that prevent a global address from showing up. To name a few: Misconfigured firewalls, IPv4-only router in between, SLAAC / DHCPv6 not in use (by your ISP or by your computer), ISP demands extra payment / checkbox clicking for IPv6.